# Automatically building SelectList based on user access level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented an access levels system that prevents/allows access to different document types.

I have a few index pages which can list multiple types of documents. These can be filtered using a dropdownlist.

I can't think of a way that I can automatically bind the dropdownlist appropriately, so that it doesn't show documents that the current user doesn't have access to.

Is there some custom model binding / generics / html helper magic that will help me out, or am I being too perfectionist?

My code atm:

```
ViewBag.DocumentTypesList = new SelectList(
               new Dictionary<DocumentTypeForUI, string>
                            {
                                { DocumentTypeForUI.Invoice, DocumentType.Invoice.Localize() },
                                { DocumentTypeForUI.CreditNote, DocumentType.CreditNote.Localize() },
                            },
               "Key",
               "Value",
               ViewBag.Type);
```

What I don't want to have to repeat on every index page:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<DocumentTypeForUI, string>();

if (CurrentUser.HasAccessTo(DocumentType.Invoice))
{
    dict.Add({ DocumentTypeForUI.Invoice, DocumentType.Invoice.Localize() });
}

if (CurrentUser.HasAccessTo(DocumentType.CreditNote))
{
    dict.Add({ DocumentTypeForUI.CreditNote, DocumentType.CreditNote.Localize() });
}

ViewBag.DocumentTypesList = new SelectList(
    dict,
    "Key",
    "Value",
    ViewBag.Type);
```

The ideal:

```
ViewBag.DocumentTypesList = Magic.GenerateASelectListFor({DocumentType.Invoice, Documentype.CreditNote});
```

Comment: This shouldn't really be handled by your MVC app at all - filtering things by permissions should be in a business logic/service layer. That way your MVC app can just display whatever it gets back.

Comment: Correct. I am trying to move it to business logic. This question is really about how I can do this, and apply that logic to UI elements in a reusable way.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the answer: just make "Magic" a static class with a method called "GenerateASelectListFor". Then, in your Views, skip the ViewBag entirely. Your Views can talk to any public classes in your namespace.

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{

    public static class Magic
    {
        public static SelectList GenerateASelectListFor()
        {
            // your code here obviously....
            return new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Foo", "Barr" }, { "Car", "Dog" } });
        }
    }
}
```

And in your View its as easy as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Foo", YourNameSpace.Magic.GenerateASelectListFor())
```

You will just need to make sure the `Web.config` **in the root of your `Views` folder** (*not the main Web.config*) has an entry for your namespace:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="YourNameSpace"/>
</namespaces>
```

---

A a side note, you should look into dumping the whole ViewBag/ViewData paradigm in favor of Views strongly typed against ViewModels, which are classes created solely for the purpose of getting just what you need from the Business layer to each View. They eliminate the problematic usage of ViewBag, which works like Session/Cookie/etc, where you need to remember what objects/types are thrown into it via string names. Since ViewModels look just like normal classes, you can apply all the normal types of inheritance to them to power the kind of reusability you are needing in this question.

For example, if every page/View in a given section of you app needed the above filtered Select Lists, you could have all those ViewModels inherit from a base that implemented the filtration and had a `public SelectList DocumentTypeChoices { get; set; }` prop, where you'd put your logic in once. Just a suggestion!

Comment: Very interesting. I think I should use an extension function for this however. Would that work?  public static MvcHtmlString MagicDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes, User currentUser){...}

Comment: I prefer to keep my `HtmlHelper` extensions less app-specific so I can just throw the library into the next project, but you certainly could do that if that's a consistent pattern in your app.